# How can I add a href in JSON script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

i want to create site web multi language i need to add some link in my JSON return how to fix this code
How can I add a link to my script line such as when I click to this link this opened to my source like a  HTML.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var arrLang = {
  'en': {
    'home': 'Home',
    'about': 'About Us',
    'contact': 'Contact Us',
    'desc': 'This is my description',
    'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_-t-8WFbSs&ab_channel=Gultrahsoundsystemofficiel'

  },
  'km': {
    'home': 'ទំព័រដើម',
    'about': 'អំពីយើង',
    'contact': 'ទំនាក់ទំនងយើងខ្ញុំ',
    'desc': 'នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទរបស់ខ្ញុំ',
    'link': 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp'
  }
};

// Process translation
$(function() {
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
  <a href="#" id="en" class="translate">English</a>
  <a href="#" id="km" class="translate">ខ្មែរ</a>

   <ul>
<li class="lang" key="home">Home</li>
<li class="lang" key="about">About Us</li>
<li class="lang" key="contact">Contact Us</li>
<a href="#" id="lang" key="link">go to</a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).find("a").attr("href", arrLang[lang].link)` ? Or append a new `<a>`

Comment: $('#lang').attr("href", arrLang[lang].link)

Comment: you have already defined id for hyperlink